# c# NetFwTypeLib как в фаерволле удалить все правила по названию группы?

Tags: c#, windows, firewall

Я нашел лишь способ удалять по точному названию правила.

```
_firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove("AdBlocker_TEST_Rule");
```

например есть несколько правил с названием "TestRule". Как удалить их все?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в `Rules` список всех правил. Выберите нужные вам обычным запросом:

```
_firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>.Select...
```

А потом удалите те, которые попали в вашу выборку.

Answer (score 3):

спасибо большое Bezarius'у:

```
public void CleanUpRules()
        {
            var rulesToDelete = _firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>();

            foreach (var rule in rulesToDelete)
            {
                if (rule.Grouping != null && rule.Grouping.Contains("GroupNamePart"))
                {
                    _firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove(rule.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```